# Directory redirect with htaccess and duplicated content

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I got a problem with my subdirectory redirecting. I've got this project structure:

- public_html

  - public

    - landing-page
    - nuxt_app
    - app
    - .htaccess

In this structure I have app which is located in public_html/public/app and url to it is like this: [www.example.com/app](http://www.example.com/app) and I have landing-page dir which url is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). I've used httpd configuration to move root directory from public_html to public_html/public and htaccess file to move everything from landing-page to root dir

My main problem is with .htaccess file which partialy works it shows content from landing-page in root directory but also shows content in url: [www.example.com/landing-page](http://www.example.com/landing-page) and generates duplicate content

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/landing-page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /landing-page/$1 [NC,L]
```

Using redirect like this:

```
Redirect /landing-page/ https://example.com/
```

causes infinite loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `DocumentRoot` has been set to `public_html/public`, you can try this .htaccess inside `public/` directory:

```bash
RewriteEngine on

# external redirect to remove landing-page from external URLs
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^landing-page/(.*) /$1 [R=301,NC,L,NE]

# internal rewrite to add landing-page silently
RewriteRule !^landing-page/ landing-page%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```